# Get multiple rows with one query in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I get build a QuerySet that gets multiple rows from django? I thought filter() would work, but it seems to be worse off.

For example, I have two rows in the model Car, with two text attributes (license and vin). Now say I want to print the licenses and vins from these cars. How can I do that with one database call?

Here's an answer that will make two database calls:

```
#using get(), two total queries
a = Car.objects.get(id=1) #query here
b = Car.objects.get(id=2) #query here
print(a.license + a.vin) #no query
print(b.license + b.vin) #no query
```

That obviously didn't work because I made two get() queries. So next I'll try filter():

```
#using filter(), four total queries
c = Car.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2)) #no query
print(c[0].license + c[0].vin) #two queries
print(c[1].license + c[1].vin) #two queries
```

Hmmm, that's weird, why is making four database calls? Is there a way I can make it get the two in one database call?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's seems weird because of how indexing into a queryset works.

```
c = list(Car.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2))) # query
print(c[0].license + c[0].vin) #no query
print(c[1].license + c[1].vin) #no query
```

If you do the following, you'll only have one query too:

```
for car in Car.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2)):
    print(car.license + car.vin)
```

As @Torsten said, in your situation it appears like you're simply trying to get *all* the cars you've created. This can be achieved via the `all()` method:

```
for car in Car.objects.all():
    print(car.license + car.vin)
```

Comment: Well that is silly. All I needed to do was put a list() in front of it? Crazy. Thanks! For extra karma: Can anyone explain why list() is needed and why it doesn't make the query to start?

Comment: Well when you index into a queryset, it thinks you just want a single item from that queryset, so it doesn't perform a query for the entire thing, it just does a single query for the single item you want. But yes, I can see how it would seem pretty weird :(

Comment: Also you might consider `Car.objects.all()` instead of `filter` to get all the objects from the database.

Comment: The only unclear thing here is that if the result is sorted or not. I mean, if I give the `id__in`s in `(3,1,2)` order, do I get it in this exact order or standard ascending `id`s?

Comment: @ErayErdin no, order is not preserved. [Django's "in" lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) transforms to SQL "WHERE ... IN ..." clause.

Answer (score 7):

Great example.  A typo I think though in your last codeblock.  Should be:

```
for car in Car.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2)):
    print(car.license + car.vin)
```

How does that method stack up